# Module to manage submodules

Tags: 7

What I want to do is be able to tell what the parent of a submodule is on the admin/modules page. There is little to no indication of what it belongs to sometimes.

Example, under the Administration group, I have a module called "Actions permissions." I have no idea what this module is for, the purpose of the module, why I would want it, or what it belongs to. It's just out there. I know it's a child of something else, but there is no indication of that anywhere. I could go on the server and grep it but I think it might be helpful to people to have a way to determine the parent.

So is there a module that:

A) will group submodules in a hierarchy-type view under their parents? Or
B) a module that simply lists what the parent is on the module item itself like we do with Requires:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such concept as parent and sub/child-modules in Drupal. You'd have to define what *you* consider to be the parent-child relationship, pick what physical properties of the module you're going to use to describe that relationship, and code a solution from there.

Drupal's own native mechanism for grouping modules is using the `package` key in the module .info file. In the case of Actions Permissions, for example, the package is defined as "Administration", so you can find it under the "Administration" fieldset, grouped with other modules that are considered to have (loosely) related functionality by their respective authors.

On a slightly un-related note, but you can improve the UI of the modules page using [Module Filter](http://drupal.org/project/module_filter) if it's becoming unwieldy.

Comment: Ugh. I remember now hearing that about no concept of parent modules in Drupal. I think that's a bad decision but I guess it is what it is. I'd define a parent-child relationship simply as a module that exists in the same directory as the parent module. Pretty simple. Might be doable at some point in the future. Also, I'm already using the Module Filter module and it's one of the first modules I like to install.

Comment: I think the main problem is the freedom Drupal has given to arbitrarily choose packages. Even when there are some sort of standard attempted by a project the individual contributors choose packages all willy nilly. I will probably investigate some kind of module control manager-type module in the module. Something that can override module packages and things like that at the Drupal level instead of going into the modules themselves as that won't be very upgrade friendly.